# put wpf control on top of a win32 control

Tags: c#, wpf, winapi

I have a win32 window that i'm hosting in a WPF window, and I need to put another control on top of that window (something like a video, and subtitles on top of it)
but for some reason i don't see the control that i put over the window.
this is what i've got so far:

```
<Grid>
    <Border Name="ControlHostElement" Background="Black" SizeChanged="ControlHostElement_SizeChanged" />
    <View:MospView />
</Grid>
```

`VideoHostControl` is a `HwndHost` class

```
    public static readonly DependencyProperty VideoWindowProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("VideoWindow", typeof(IntPtr), typeof(VideoView),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(IntPtr.Zero, new PropertyChangedCallback(VideoWindowChanged)));

    public IntPtr VideoWindow
    {
        get { return (IntPtr)GetValue(VideoWindowProperty); }
        set { SetValue(VideoWindowProperty, value); }
    }

    private static void VideoWindowChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        VideoView view = sender as VideoView;
        if (view == null) return;
        view.ControlHostElement.Child = view.VideoHost = new VideoHostControl(view.VideoWindow);
        view.ControlHostElement_SizeChanged(sender, null);
    }

    private void ControlHostElement_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (VideoHost != null)
        {
            double width = viewBoxWraper.ActualWidth * ControlHostElement.ActualWidth / grid.ActualWidth;
            double height = viewBoxWraper.ActualHeight * ControlHostElement.ActualHeight / grid.ActualHeight;
            VideoHost.Resize((int)width, (int)height);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should try using a popup or another window for your subtitles. You can't just "put wpf control on top of a win32 control".